# Gatling: Try to check back-end is UP before starting simulation

Tags: scala, spring-boot, gatling, spring-boot-actuator, scala-gatling

I try to check if my Spring Boot back-end is UP before starting the whole simulation.

I guess I could do so using the doWhileDuring loop.

I tried something like this with no success:

```
doWhileDuring(
  condition = "${!isUp}",
  duration = 1 minute,
  counterName = "Wait for microservice to be up"
) {
  exec(
    http(
      requestName = "HealthCheck"
    ).get(
      url = "/actuator/health"
    ).check(
      bodyString.is(
        expected = """{"status":"UP"}"""
      ).saveAs("isUp")
    )
  )
}
```

But the way I save the isUp variable may not be the right one and the loop doesn't lock the launch of the Simulation.

Also tried the following but does not work neither:

```
  doWhileDuring(
    condition = "${!isUp.equalsIgnoreCase(\"UP\")}",
    duration = 1 minute,
    counterName = "Wait for microservice to be up"
  ) {
    exec(
      http(
        requestName = "HealthCheck"
      ).get(
        url = "/actuator/health"
      ).check(
        jsonPath("$.status").saveAs("isUp")
      )
    )
  }
```

Could you help me to find the good way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> The Gatling EL is not a dynamic language, but just placeholders with a few additional helpers.

https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el

The only dynamic capabilities are the built-in functions listed. Using `!` as "not" is not one of them.

This one suits your need though.

```
"${foo.isUndefined()}"   // returns true if the session doesn't contains a `foo` attribute, false otherwise
```